# "buttons" now have oversized abbreviated text

Tags: ipados

I just updated my iPad to iPadOS13.1.2 and after a few stumbles it seems to be working well.

There is one disturbing "feature" I can't seem to avoid.

In the **Stack Exchange** app the posts used to have "buttons" - these now have oversized abbreviated text; **Edit** becomes **E.** **Close** becomes **Cl…**

Is there any way of restoring normal behaviour (probably reducing text size)?
**Text Size** in **Display & Brightness** reduces the size of text - EXCEPT for the text on "buttons"